# Android M get all dangerous permissions listed in the manifest

Tags: android

I want to ask the user for all the needed permissions the first time my app runs.

However I do not want to hard code the `Dangerous Permissions` in code, as this makes my code a whole lot less manageable.

Is there possibly a way in which I can query and get all dangerous permissions that I have already listed in the `Manifest.xml`

Comment: You are certainly welcome to use `PackageManager` to find out the permissions that your application requests. I think you can also then find out which of those are `dangerous`. Conservatively, this will be 1-2 orders of magnitude more complex than a `static String[]` of permissions that should rarely change.

Answer (score 3):

As CommonsWare pointed out in the comments, it would be better to use a `static String[]` of all the dangerous permissions than get a list of them using `PackageManager`. You can use the following method to get a list of dangerous permissions of your app or any app:

```
public static List<PermissionInfo> getDangerousPermissions(Context context, String packageName)
    throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
  List<PermissionInfo> dangerousPermissions = new ArrayList<>();
  PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
  PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
  if (packageInfo.requestedPermissions != null) {
    for (String requestedPermission : packageInfo.requestedPermissions) {
      try {
        PermissionInfo permissionInfo = pm.getPermissionInfo(requestedPermission, 0);
        switch (permissionInfo.protectionLevel & PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_MASK_BASE) {
          case PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_DANGEROUS:
            dangerousPermissions.add(permissionInfo);
            break;
        }
      } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ignored) {
        // unknown permission
      }
    }
  }
  return dangerousPermissions;
}
```

Example usage:

```
try {
  List<PermissionInfo> dangerousPermissions = getDangerousPermissions(this, "com.android.chrome");
  System.out.println(String.format("%d dangerous permissions:", dangerousPermissions.size()));
  for (PermissionInfo dangerousPermission : dangerousPermissions) {
    System.out.println(dangerousPermission.name);
  }
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
I/System.out: 7 dangerous permissions:
I/System.out: android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
I/System.out: android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
I/System.out: android.permission.CAMERA
I/System.out: android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
I/System.out: android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
I/System.out: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
I/System.out: android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```